# Creating an unlocked package: how to specify the target org required features?

Tags: salesforcedx

We are working in SFDX and we created several scratch org with "FieldAuditTrail" active so we could increase the number of fields under history. However, when we try to create a package via the sfdx CLI it fails with

> exceeded the allowed number of fields to track on a given entity

We correctly configured the project-scratch-def.json for scratch org, how do we specify package requirements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify a definition file in your `sfdx-project.json` file (using the `definitionFile` property) or pass in a path to one with the `--definitionfile` flag when you run the command to create your package version. The definition file has the same structure as a scratch org definition to specify the features/settings required by your package.

There's more info on the [Unlocked Packages page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_unlocked_pkg_config_file.htm) in the developer guide:

> A reference to an external .json file used to specify the features and org settings required for the metadata of your package, such as the scratch org definition.
>   Example: `"definitionFile": "config/project-scratch-def.json",`